# Is there a way to install MD5 without using apt-get?

Tags: installation, apt

Is there a way to install MD5 in Ubuntu without using apt-get?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the question. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 7):

You don't have to install anything. The `coreutils` package is a dependency of the Kernel amongst almost a dozen other very standard packages. You'd have to fight quite hard to remove the package.

You use it through `md5sum` which by default takes a file as its main argument. It's fairly easy to use it in an interactive setting though:

```
oli@bert:~$ md5sum - <<<"This is a test hash"
6b7cf77ca6403a2323e5fd98a462538e  -

oli@bert:~$ echo "This is a test hash" | md5sum 
6b7cf77ca6403a2323e5fd98a462538e  -
```

But it has other functions, run `man md5sum` to see them.

TL;DR: it's installed by default.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with apt-get? Do you mean md5sum?

```
apt-cache search md5sum
coreutils - The GNU core utilities
```

Install it from synaptics. Start synaptic, search for md5 if you mean something else.

Comment: However, synaptic is apt-get - under a GUI shell.

Comment: But we don't know what is wrong with apt. Maybe it _is_ a GUI-question?

Comment: Perhaps it is a GUI question. I was just saying that Synaptics is apt-get, but it's not apt-get.